# Solving a special differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Any hints how to solve the following differential equation,
$$y'(x)=(\sin (y(x)+C_1)-C_2)^2,\,\, C_1, C_2 \in \mathbb{R}?$$
I know how to solve linear ODE, but I'm stuck with this one.

Comment: I do not have a step-by-step solution to offer but at least wolframalpha can solve this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%28t%29%3Dsin%28y%28t%29%2Bc_1%29-c_2

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: My bad, there is a square on the righthand side

Comment: this is separable. so just integrate.

Comment: It's a separable ODE so it boils down to computing the integral$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{(\sin(y+C_1)-C_2)^2}$$whatever that is

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot

Comment: Apply the half-angle-tangent substitution, then partial-fraction decomposition.